# mod_rewrite into subdirectory file from folder

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This could be probably duplicate  due to unable to find that original even after checked the similar questions list of stackoverflow. Actually if user type myipaddress/gt then it should redirect to myipaddress/gt/gt.htm
I tried various mod_rewrites but still gets the 'gt' folder contents listed in browser. I gave the last try with below mod_rewrite.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^gt$ gt/gt.htm [NC,L]
```

But still the browser shows the contents of the 'gt' folder. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule in **`/gt/.htaccess`**:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /gt/

RewriteRule ^/?$ gt.php [L]
```

Comment: your mod_rewrite worked. Thank you for your solution.

Comment: I forgot that only clicking on tick mark will make this solution as accepted answer and not clicking on up-arrow key. Now I marked it.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the fact that Apache sees `gt` as a directory, it treats it as such. However, that doesn't stop all rewriting for that particular path.

This is the basic process:

1. You navigate to `/gt`.
2. Apache sees that as an **existing** directory, and thus redirects to `/gt/`.
3. Your rule is ignored, because it doesn't contain the trailing slash.

This is why you still see the directory listing.

As such, you should change your rule to this:

```
RewriteRule ^gt/$ gt/gt.php [NC,L]
```

Alternatively, you can make use of `DirectorySlash off` and make the trailing slash optional, like so:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
DirectorySlash off

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^gt/?$ gt/gt.php [NC,L]
```

Doing either of the above allows you to have multiple rules of a similar nature in a single `.htaccess` file.

Comment: Thank you for your idea. I am trying with your mod_rewrite (it seems I miss something with it) since I still get the directory list.

Comment: It's more than likely a cache issue. If you clear your browser's cache, it should work.